# How to surround groups of XHTML nodes with a <div> using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xhtml, xslt-2.0

My XHTML input:

```
<h1 class="section">Text</h1>
<h2 class="section">More text</h2>
```

Desired XHTML output:

```
<div class="section">
<h1 class="section">Text</h1>
<h2 class="section">More text</h2>
</div>
```

Therefore, the `group-adjacent` approach seems suitable. The code below will do the right thing with the `h1` and `h2` nodes, but it will erase everything else in the `<body>` node including the `<body>` tags themselves.

Clearly I'm making an error, but I'm not enough of an expert with `for-each-group` to understand where it is.

Thanks.

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:body"> 
    <xsl:for-each-group select="xhtml:h1|xhtml:h2" group-adjacent="@class"> 
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()='section'">
                <xsl:element name="div">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/> 
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />    
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>            
    </xsl:for-each-group>  
</xsl:template>
```

**Update**: What I didn't understand is that `for-each-group` essentially acts as a filter on whatever node you point it at. Therefore, if you want to preserve every subnode, the original command has to include `select="*"`. Furthermore, the grouping rule has to ensure that every subnode will end up in a group. This means `group-adjacent` is not right tool for the job; `group-starting-with` is.

The template below separates the whole `<body>` of the XHTML file into groups that start with `h1`. (Be warned: This grouping rule relies on the assumption that an `h1` is always the first subnode in the `<body>` of the XHTML.) Then I loop over the groups, using a conditional to look at the first two nodes in each group to see if they match my criteria. If so, I wrap them in my `<div>`.

I'd still be interested whether there's a more idiomatic XSLT solution, as what I've done is basically write Python within XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:body"> 
    <xsl:copy>            
    <!--Divide file into groups of nodes starting with h1 tags-->
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="xhtml:h1"> 
        <xsl:choose>
            <!-- if the group starts with h1.section + h2.section -->
            <xsl:when test="current-group()[1][@class='section'] and current-group()[2][name() = 'h2'] and current-group()[2][@class = 'section']">
                <!--wrap in a div tag-->
                <div class="section">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[2]"/>
                </div>                    
                <!--then process the rest of the nodes in this group normally-->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[position()>=3]"/> 
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!--process normally-->
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/> 
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group> 
    </xsl:copy>  
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You have forgotten to provide the source X(ht)ML document. You also haven't provided the exact wanted result. Please, edit the question and specify this important information to make this a meaningful question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your update to the question, you've identified part of the answer. However, it's possible to solve this kind of problem with group-adjacent. The usual pattern is to compute a grouping key of "true" for the elements to be wrapped as a group, and "false" for the others. So the coding pattern is:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="self::h1 or self::h2">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
      <div>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </div>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```